# iPhone control an app from another iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitouch, nsstream

I have a request from a client to do an Enterprise app.

The app itself is fairly straight forward, but they want user to be able to request help from admin. When right are granted, Admin will be able to controller the user app from his/her app.

I am really stuck on  how would I go about doing this. I listed some steps that I think are needed but it is a best guess.

**1 user/admin established a secure Authentication**

1.1 user request help with random number generate

1.2 admin got the number via phone or sms then input the gen number in his/her app to link this two app together

**2 user app steam screenshot of its app to the admin app**

**3 admin app receives screenshots stream and show on admin screen**

**4 admin app detect and steam UITouch events to user app**

**5 user app listen to the steam UITouch events from admin and pass on to UIKit component**

any suggestion is welcome.

Thankz so much in advance

Pondd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a VNC server. The VNC protocol handles all the screen and interaction synchronization over the network.

While there are a couple of VNC clients for the iPhone, I'm not aware of an open source server project. So you'd have to do the port by yourself. The authorization aspect is another task that VNC won't handle for you. VNC has only simple name/password authorization, which you might use after the manual challenge response over telephone.

It might be difficult to do the VNC port in an App-Store compatible way (i.e. without using private APIs) since you'd have to generate `UITouch` events and insert them into the event stream.